# Heroku - invalid byte sequence in US-ASCII (ArgumentError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, ruby-1.9

Today I got this error in two projects on Heroku when I try to push my changes.

I tried to set

```
encoding: utf-8
```

I tried to put these lines

```
LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8"
```

But they didn't work.

It worked only when I migrated my stack to bamboo-ree-1.8.7. But I would like to use bamboo-mri-1.9.2.

Anyone notice this same problem?

Cheers

Comment: Did you set encoding utf 8 in all the source files that Use non ascii chars?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "problem" is on simple_form.gemspec, actually it isn't a real problem on it. The simple_form.gemspec contains accents:

https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/blob/master/simple_form.gemspec

```
 s.authors     = ['José Valim', 'Carlos Antônio']
```

and bamboo-mri-1.9.2 can't deal with it.

I created an issue on simple_form and on heroku support. Both said to me to fork simple_form and remove the accents on gemspec and then point my gem to my fork

```
 gem "simple_form", :git => "git://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form.git"
```

I didn't like it, but I think that is the "solution" for now.

https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/issues/361

Comment: vote up for this one, cause it helped me and I am sure will help you too, hwoever you are :)  . thanks Pablo.

Answer (score 1):

Try reverting to old Gemfile.lock version and deployed to heroku again. It worked for me.

One of following updates caused the issue:

```
- coffee-script-source (1.1.2)
+ coffee-script-source (1.1.3)

- ffi (1.0.9)
+ ffi (1.0.10)

- guard-rspec (0.5.2)
+ guard-rspec (0.5.3)

- jquery-rails (1.0.16)
+ jquery-rails (1.0.17)

- selenium-webdriver (2.10.0)
+ selenium-webdriver (2.12.0)

- tzinfo (0.3.30)
+ tzinfo (0.3.31)
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try deploying your app on the cedar stack: http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/cedar

Comment: Unfortunately Heroku doesn't allow to migrate from bamboo to cedar. :/

Comment: You are right, so you should deploy as a new app on the cedar. I have faced with this problema and heroku support team said that answer.